# convert G.723.1 to normal wav and split channels?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I have a wav file who's info is

```
ion@aurora:~/Inbound$ mediainfo 48401-3405-48403--18042018170000.wav 
General
Complete name                            : 48401-3405-48403--18042018170000.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 327 KiB
Duration                                 : 4mn 11s
Overall bit rate                         : 10.7 Kbps

Audio
Format                                   : G.723.1
Codec ID                                 : A100
Duration                                 : 4mn 11s
Bit rate                                 : 10.7 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz
Stream size                              : 327 KiB (100%)
```

and the audacity shows like this
[image]

To tackle it I tried

```
ffmpeg -i 48401-3405-48403--18042018170000.wav  -f wav test.wav
```

But it just appends the second channel at the back of first channel , So I get only single channel.
and its media info is:
ion@aurora:~/Inbound$ mediainfo test.wav

```
General
Complete name                            : test.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 7.67 MiB
Duration                                 : 8mn 22s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 8mn 22s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 7.67 MiB (100%)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: When I hear the original wav file, It feels like the talking is too fast.

This is how the media info of processed file should look like.

```
ion@aurora:~/Downloads/Call Recordings$ mediainfo 9417648939\ \(G\ Call\)_Done.wav 
General
Complete name                            : 9417648939 (G Call)_Done.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 8.01 MiB
Duration                                 : 8mn 44s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps

Audio
Format                                   : ADPCM
Format profile                           : U-Law
Codec ID                                 : 7
Codec ID/Hint                            : CCITT
Duration                                 : 8mn 44s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Stream size                              : 8.01 MiB (100%)
```

Comment: Upload the full log of ffmpeg command.

Comment: @Gyan find the logs here [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KHCPsDcko7t7KF4b0qIR3lCJElWi__1UWfaVKF1rsPA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you want I can share the audio file too.

Comment: ffmpeg is seeing this file as mono: `Stream #0:0: Audio: g723_1 ([0][161][0][0] / 0xA100), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 10 kb/s`. Which tool converts this correctly?

Comment: I don't know , Thats why I am asking here , How will I convert this audio file.

Comment: Which tool produced the 'processed file'?

Comment: That was sent by someone who isn't available now to tell me how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170138/discussion-between-ryan-adlob-and-gyan).

Answer (score 0):

1) ffmpeg from ubuntu (18.04) repository has a bug (ffmpeg does not detect stereo channel in g723). Use FFmpeg from git repository https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

```
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
cd FFmpeg/ && ./configure --disable-x86asm && make
```

2) Now you can convert audio:

```
FFmpeg/ffmpeg -i test.g723 test.wav
```

3) And separate channels:

```
FFmpeg/ffmpeg -i test.wav -filter_complex 'channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[L][R]' -map '[L]' test.wav -map '[R]' test.wav
```